# Updating one single record in array inside Mongo Collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

Hi Guys i am trying to add some fields and update the existing fields to existing mongodb document array. Since i am new to mongo i dont have much idea how to operate on nested documents inside array. My Array is like

```
    "productVersions" : [ 
    {
        "productVersion" : "1.0",
        "active" : true,
        "effectiveDate" : "01/09/2020",
        "versionDescription" : "Initial version"
    }, 
    {
        "productVersion" : "2.0",
        "active" : true,
        "effectiveDate" : "01/09/2020",
        "versionDescription" : "Initial version"
    }
]
```

first i want to find the correct productVersion and then in that productVersion update the existing fields and if field does not exist add it.
Below are some of the fields which i want to add to productVersion2 as can be seen the effectiveDate is already there which must get updated and rest of the fields should get added.

```
      {signatureId: 123,
      signatureURL: 'www.abc.com',
      effectiveDate: "01/09/2020",
      configurationStatus: "active",
      name: "john"}
```

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) to update the array. If the field already exists then the value of the field get updated and if the not new field gets added

```js
db.collection.update(
  { "productVersions.productVersion": "2.0" },
  {
    $set: {
      "productVersions.$.signatureId": 123,
      "productVersions.$.signatureURL": "www.abc.com",
      "productVersions.$.effectiveDate": "01/09/2020",
      "productVersions.$.configurationStatus": "active",
      "productVersions.$.name": "john",
    },
  }
);
```